# Vector Initialisation in C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector, declaration, stdvector

I am using Vectors in my code.

The line that is causing the error is as follows :

```
vector<Node> alt_seq ;
alt_seq = vector<Node>(1000);
for(int j=0; j<alt_cf.getNoOfNodes(i); j++)
{
    Node temp_node = *alt_itr;
    alt_itr++;
    alt_seq.push_back(temp_node);
    }
```

The line :

```
 alt_seq.push_back(temp_node);
```

causes a runtime error. However if I initialise the Vector with some initial size  as follows:

```
vector<Node> alt_seq(1000) ;
```

In this case the code works fine.
However I do not want to give an initial size as the number of objects in the vector will be variable at runtime. 
Please help me. I am new with C++.

For your reference the complete Method function is here :

http://pastebin.com/2dUFEui5

Comment: Looks like a problem with class `Node`'s big-three implementations. Can you show us the definition of `Node`?

Comment: `vector<Node> alt_seq(1000)` will construct 1000 `Node` objects in the vector, which is not the same as not specifying a count. Your `push_back` problem sounds like a possible issue with the assignment/copy constructor of `Node`. Can you show the declaration and definition of the class?

Comment: BTW, the pastebin link does not have the definition for class `Node` either.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zDbJikK7 This is the link to node.h and node.cpp

Comment: @dirkgently   Link to node.h and node.cpp

http://pastebin.com/zDbJikK7

Comment: @dirkgently  http://pastebin.com/g2n14awz   link to modified code...still giving error

Comment: edit your question to include the requisit code, don't give us links to pastebin that will eventually link rot

Answer (score 3):

Your `Node` class has a pointer member of type `CombinedFragment*` called `cfrag`. This creates dangling references if you don't defined your own copy ctor and assignment operators. Further, a proper dtor is required to prevent leaks if `Node` is responsible for allocating/deallocating `cfrag`. If you don't want to deep-copy `CombinedFragment` you can use a `shared_ptr`.

Also, the default ctor for `Node` probably doesn't even need to be there (it leaves `cfrag` to an uninitialized state).

Comment: Thank you I shall try that...If you wish to look at other classes in the project, the code can be found at GitHub

https://github.com/abhinavarora/mbt

Comment: @AbhinavArora: Try to add the proper big three and get back if that doesn't solve your problem!

Comment: As you said I added the big three as follows  http://pastebin.com/g2n14awz  Please let me know if this addition is correct. Despite making the above changes it still gives a run time error. Please Help. I am failing to understand my mistake.

Comment: `this->cfrag = frag;` looks suspect to me. When you copy you are making a couple of pointers pointing to the same `CombinedFragment` object. Now, if one of them is deleted, the other one becomes a dangling pointer. Any access to that `cfrag` object is UB. So, instead of a raw pointer, try and use a `shared_ptr<CombinedFragment>` as a member so that even after deleting a `Node` object you do not lose the `CombinedFragment` object shared with by other live `Node` objects. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem; when you declare 1000 `vector` objects and then do a `push_back` you're adding to the end of the vector, i.e. the objects that you're trying to add are at 1001, 1002.... etc. If declaring 1000 `vector` objects doesn't give you a runtime error, I would first see what's the default definition (since the first 1000 node objects have default values), since that's not error out and compare against the actual data I'm trying to load. Hope this helps.