# Vector C++ error

Tags: c++, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vector Initialisation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367605/vector-initialisation-in-c)

I am using Vectors in my code.

The line that is causing the error is as follows :

```
vector<Node> alt_seq ;
for(int j=0; j<alt_cf.getNoOfNodes(i); j++)
{
    Node temp_node = *alt_itr;
    alt_itr++;
    alt_seq.push_back(temp_node);
}
```

The line :

```
alt_seq.push_back(temp_node);
```

causes a runtime error. However if I initialise the Vector with some initial size as follows:

vector alt_seq(1000) ;
In this case the code works fine. However I do not want to give an initial size as the number of objects in the vector will be variable at runtime. Please help me. I am new with C++.

For your reference the complete Method function is here :

http://pastebin.com/2dUFEui5

The Definitions for the Class Node are here:

http://pastebin.com/zDbJikK7

Comment: alt_itr is an iterator to a vector of Node Objects

Comment: could you post what runtime error it causes?

Comment: how does the line `alt_seq = vector<Node>;` not cause an error? that is clearly illegal.

Comment: That line is useless anyway, since `vector<Node> alt_seq;` initializes `alt_seq` already.

Comment: I am sorry guys I corrected the code in question, I typed a wrong line int the code. The code which you see right now is the one that is causing error. 

I use code::blocks. So when I compile and run, it crashes in between. If I comment out the    alt_seq.push_back(temp_node), the code works else it crashes.

Alternatively it works if I give an initial size to the vector

Comment: Are you sure you increment the iterator `alt_itr` correctly? If you don't ensure that it remains within the bounds of its vector, it might start referencing to an invalid memory address, therefore causing an error when you try to dereference it.

Comment: Even if you comment out that line and the program works, that does not indicate that line is the source of the problem. It is likely that something breaks after the code in question. If you are on unix, please use gdb or valgrind to find the exact line of code that breaks, as I doubt the line in question is actually causing the runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that std::vector *is* dynamically sized. The initial value is just a initial value, but if you store 2000 elements, it will grow to fit them (although it will be less efficient because of reallocation).

Comment: Yes but what is the problem with the current code ??

Answer (score 0):

You've made mistake in Node's [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) and assignment operator by using default ones.
Vector copies data inside it on reallocations, and that copy operation is producing multiple Nodes with that same cfrag member.